# How to retrieve key, value pair in one shot?

Tags: java, collections

Is there any way to get key, value pair in one shot ?
please suggest any logic for

Comment: map.entrySet(). Pleaaaaaase refer documentation

Comment: This is probably one of the most unclear questions I've seen in a long time.  Please [edit] to clarify exactly what you're after.

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve or paste what you have tried. The question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to iterate over a [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) of a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can directly refer to the [entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet())

```
Map<String, Object> map = ...
for (Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()){
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Object value = entry.getValue();
}
```

Comment: as mentioned above read the api docs